# array javascript ordering multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array that i have ordred by name but how to order by 1st surname an 2nd surname.

Could you please help me?

```
  x=100
    var  miArray = [["john", "doe", "man"],
                    ["doe", "man", "john"],
                    ["man", "john"],
                    ["ferrer", "hunt", "doe"],
                    ["hunt", "ferrer", "Blanch"],
                    ["fontar", "gonza", "ferrer"],
                    ["gonza", "lopo", "fontar"],
                    ["lopo",  "fontar", "gonza"],
                    ["mortar", "fanta", "lopo"],
                    ["fanta", "mortar"],
                    ["cola", "fanta"]];
   document.write("Ordered by name<br><br>");
    miArray.sort();
    document.write("["+miArray.join("]-[")+"]<br/>");
```

Comment: What result do you expect ? Could you post example.

Comment: i expect a ordered list by names and list by surnames

Answer (score 0):

You can order the array using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) providing a custom function:

```
var  miArray = [["john", "doe", "man"],
                ["doe", "man", "john"],
                ["man", "john"],
                ["ferrer", "hunt", "doe"],
                ["hunt", "ferrer", "Blanch"],
                ["fontar", "gonza", "ferrer"],
                ["gonza", "lopo", "fontar"],
                ["lopo",  "fontar", "gonza"],
                ["mortar", "fanta", "lopo"],
                ["fanta", "mortar"],
                ["cola", "fanta"]];

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a[0] > b[0]) {// bigger
    return 1;
  }
  if (a[0] < b[0]) {// smaller
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;// equal
}

function compareArray(a,b) {// Order by name, if names are equal by first surname, if first surname is equal, then by second surname.
    var res = 0;

    res= compare(a[0],b[0]);

    if( res === 0 ) { // First name is equal
        res = compare(a[1],b[1]); 
        if( res === 0 ) { // Second Name is equal
            return compare(a[2],b[2]);// Third name rules.
        }
    }

    return res;
}

miArray.sort(compareArray);
console.log(miArray);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhvkhopm/3/)

Comment: have you checked the result in the console? As far as I can tell it's ordered by name, 1st surname and 2nd surname

Comment: You had to check the browser console to see the result... Anyway, I've changed the fiddle so that the result is shown in the screen